# Get physical keyboard layout

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, command, line

Is there a way through command line to know what keyboard physical layout a macbook has? I cannot find that specific information in system_profiler. I want to know if the computer has a US, UK, ES, etc keyboard layout.
The aim is to script it, upload it to my MDM so I can run it in all the company's laptops and find out that information.

Thanks!

running the terminal command system_profiler SPSPIDataType
it shows this:

SPI:

```
Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad:

  Product ID: 0x0278
  Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  ST Version: 8.96
  MT Version: 4.69
  Serial Number: FM7741701QVGN41A5+RNZ
  Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
  Location ID: 0x01000000
```

I run it in two different macbooks, one UK, one ES. I was hoping that the Location ID would show something different but that was not the case.

Comment: might be more appropriate on https://apple.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: Crossposted https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365752/physical-keyboard-layout-on-macbooks

Answer (score 2):

If I do this in Terminal:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist AppleSelectedInputSources | egrep -w 'KeyboardLayout Name'
```

I get this:

```
"KeyboardLayout Name" = *name of my keyboard in readable form*
```

Comment: I believe that's the user input source, so the software layout chosen. I'm behind the actual physical keyboard layout.

Comment: That is an actual keyboard. If it wasn't, it would show up with the key "InputSourceKind". If in doubt, just put in your Terminal the following `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist`and check the key AppleEnabledInputSources and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found the solution, like this:

```
ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage | awk '{print substr( $0, 56, 20)}' | tr -d "\" =|"
```

Thanks,
Federico.

Comment: Running `ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage` returns `      | | | |   |   |   |   "KeyboardLanguage" = "Swiss Multilingual Keyboard"` here, so assuming a fixed field length in `awk` is not enough: `ioreg -l | grep KeyboardLanguage | cut -d\" -f 4`. Also I doubt that `Swiss Multilingual Keyboard` is the value you are looking for.

Comment: I think this is the answer. I've got "U.S." for ANSI vs "US International Keyboard" for ISO keyboard on Polish-bought MacBooks.

Comment: A slightly different version using the same tool. I'm curious how this would work when multiple keyboards are attached to the computer but I haven't tested.
```ioreg -a -r -k KeyboardLanguage | plutil -extract 0.KeyboardLanguage xml1 -o - - | xmllint --xpath 'string(/plist/string)' -```